# Логирование и время выполнения bash скрипта

Tags: bash, логирование, время

Знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста:
1. Время работы bash  скрипта ограничено ли системой? (час два или бесконечно)
2. Включено ли логирование по умолчанию при запуске bash скрипта?(чтобы узнать на какой строке произошла ошибка и дальше выполнение скрипта было прервано). Буду благодарен за ссылки на мануал как правильно сделать логирование bash скрипта, гугл подсказывает вставлять на после каждой строки:
echo "Сообщение" »/usr/logs/file
Но это выглядит трудоемким процессом, есть альтернатива?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1. нет, время, конечно же, не ограничено
2. нет, никакого «логирования», естественно, не «включено». но вы, например, можете воспользоваться командой `set -x` где-нибудь в начале скрипта. тогда текст каждой выполняемой команды будет выводиться интерпретатором в *stderr*, и его (текст) можно будет, к примеру, перанаправить в файл:

   ```
   $ скрипт 2>файл
   ```